# Firefox remembers state of page elements

Tags: html, css, firefox

Firefox is remembering the css state of my page's elements. For example, it remembers the contents of a div that was changed before the reload, and the visibilities of certain elements. How can I make it forget all page state, without explicitly "zeroing out" those values with Javascript when the page loads?

Comment: delete your cookies, history and clear cache

Comment: @jawad, I'm the developer, I'm looking for a server-side solution

Comment: Not sure if this is as much as caching issue that can be fixed. I have noticed similar issues on forms etc in Firefox for quite some time though one thing I found consistent, "F5" refreshes of the page etc was when the state was kept, if you navigate back to the URL, it was fine. At the same time though, a little more detail over the server-side language (to potentially stop this if it is something else) and perhaps even a link to an example would be useful.

Answer (score 1):

There was a form on the page. I added `autocomplete="off"` on the form, and that fixed the issue, even though the other elements were not within the form.